# emacs savehist complains when I run multiple emacs

Tags: emacs

When I open one emacs, everything works fine.

But when I open second emacs on different terminal,

error occurs

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax "#")
  signal(invalid-read-syntax ("#"))
  (condition-case errvar (progn (load savehist-file nil (not (interactive-p))) (setq savehist-loaded t)) (error (setq savehist-mode nil) (savehist-uninstall) (signal (car errvar) (cdr errvar))))
  (progn (condition-case errvar (progn (load savehist-file nil (not (interactive-p))) (setq savehist-loaded t)) (error (setq savehist-mode nil) (savehist-uninstall) (signal (car errvar) (cdr errvar)))))
  (if (and (not savehist-loaded) (file-exists-p savehist-file)) (progn (condition-case errvar (progn (load savehist-file nil (not (interactive-p))) (setq savehist-loaded t)) (error (setq savehist-mode nil) (savehist-uninstall) (signal (car errvar) (cdr errvar))))))
  (if (not savehist-mode) (savehist-uninstall) (if (and (not savehist-loaded) (file-exists-p savehist-file)) (progn (condition-case errvar (progn (load savehist-file nil (not (interactive-p))) (setq savehist-loaded t)) (error (setq savehist-mode nil) (savehist-uninstall)$
  savehist-mode(1)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/eugenekim/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 21294
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/eugenekim/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/eugenekim/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/eugenekim/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "^H\205\266^@ \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202?^@ \311=\204^^^@\307^H\312Q\202?^@\313\307\314\315#\203*^@\316\202?^@\313\307\314\317#\203>^@\320\321\322!D\nB^R\323\202?^@\316\324^S\325^A\324\211#\210^K\324=\203e^@\326\327\330\307^H\331Q!\"\325^A\324\211#\210^K\324=\203$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

I tracked down it's `#` in `./emacs.d/history` file, everything works fine if I delete lines with `#` in the file, but I'd like to fix it once and for all :(

It seems `#` in `(setq minibuffer-history ..)` is the problem.

```
(setq minibuffer-history '("/home/eugenekim/Documents/zibann/momsite/momsite/conf/dev/webpack.config.js" #("var" 0 3 (fontified t font-lock-face font-lock-keyword-face)) "review-meta-review" "review main thread view" "11" "webpack" "/home/eugenekim/Documents/zibann-" "in\
it" #("5-static-elements" 0 17 (dired-filename t mouse-face highlight help-echo "mouse-2: visit this file in other window" fontified t)) "/home/eugenekim/tmp/react-grid-layout/test/ex" "we" "/home/eugenekim/tmp/react-grid-layout/" "inhouse webpack" "webp" "/home/eugeneki\
m/tmp/react-grid-layout/" "packa" #("To" 0 2 (magit-section [cl-struct-magit-section process #<process git> #<marker (moves after insertion) at 18819 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 18869 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 19136 in *magit-process: zibann> nil \
nil nil nil nil #<process git> [cl-struct-magit-section processbuf nil #<marker (moves after insertion) at 19302 in *magit-process: zibann> nil #<marker at 19303 in *magit-process: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ([cl-struct-magit-section process nil #<marker (moves \
after insertion) at 12596 in *magit-process: zibann> nil #<marker at 12615 in *magit-process: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section process #<process git> #<marker (moves after insertion) at 12615 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 12635 in\
 *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 12729 in *magit-process: zibann> t nil nil nil nil #<process git> #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section process #<process git> #<marker (moves after insertion) at 12729 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 12781 in *magit-process: zibann\
> #<marker at 13055 in *magit-process: zibann> t nil nil nil nil #<process git> #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section process nil #<marker (moves after insertion) at 13055 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 13094 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 13179 in *magit-proc\
ess: zibann> t nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section process nil #<marker (moves after insertion) at 13179 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 13219 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 16090 in *magit-process: zibann> t nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [c\
l-struct-magit-section process nil #<marker (moves after insertion) at 16090 in *magit-process: zibann> nil #<marker at 16146 in *magit-process: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section process nil #<marker (moves after insertion) at 16146 in *mag\
it-process: zibann> nil #<marker at 16973 in *magit-process: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section process nil #<marker (moves after insertion) at 16973 in *magit-process: zibann> nil #<marker at 16992 in *magit-process: zibann> nil nil nil nil\
 nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section process #<process git> #<marker (moves after insertion) at 16992 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 17012 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 18239 in *magit-process: zibann> t nil nil nil nil #<process git> #6 nil] [cl-st\
ruct-magit-section process nil #<marker (moves after insertion) at 18239 in *magit-process: zibann> nil #<marker at 18340 in *magit-process: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section process #<process git> #<marker (moves after insertion) at 18340 \
in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 18360 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 18449 in *magit-process: zibann> t nil nil nil nil #<process git> #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section process nil #<marker (moves after insertion) at 18449 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marke\
r at 18475 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 18534 in *magit-process: zibann> t nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section process nil #<marker (moves after insertion) at 18534 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 18568 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marke\
r at 18819 in *magit-process: zibann> t nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] #5 [cl-struct-magit-section process nil #<marker (moves after insertion) at 19136 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 19175 in *magit-process: zibann> #<marker at 19302 in *magit-process: zibann> nil \
nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil])] nil])) "/home/eugenekim/tmp/react-grid-layout/" "/home/eugenekim/tmp/react-grid-layout/package.json" "/home/eugenekim/tmp/grid" "/home/eugenekim/Documents/zibann/momsite/node_modules/react-g" "magit" "webpack" "magit:" "/home/eugenekim/Docum\
ents/zibann/momsite/apps/reservation/static/reservation/calendar/view_configs/calendar-day.react.js" "/home/eugenekim/Documents/zibann/momsite/apps/reservation/static/reservation/calendar/view_configs/month" "/home/eugenekim/Documents/zibann/momsite/apps/reservation/stat\
ic/reservation/calendar/view_configs/" "calendar view config react js" #("stash" 0 5 (face magit-hash magit-section [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{8}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil \
nil nil [cl-struct-magit-section stashes "refs/stash" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil [cl-struct-magit-section status nil #<marker (moves after insertion)\
 at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ([cl-struct-magit-section branch "feature/reservation" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann>\
 nil nil nil nil nil nil #7 ([cl-struct-magit-section branch #("origin/feature/reservation" 0 26 (face magit-branch-remote)) #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #9 nil] [cl-struct-magit-s\
ection tag "saleor" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #9 nil])] #6 [cl-struct-magit-section unpushed "@{upstream}.." #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> #<marker \
at 1 in *magit: zibann> #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #7 ([cl-struct-magit-section commit "e7b4341" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #9 nil])])] ([cl-struct-\
magit-section stash "stash@{0}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{1}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<mar\
ker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{2}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{3\
}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{4}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> n\
il nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{5}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{6}" #<marker (moves after inse\
rtion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{7}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil\
] #5 [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{9}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{10}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: \
zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{11}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-secti\
on stash "stash@{12}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{13}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 \
in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil] [cl-struct-magit-section stash "stash@{14}" #<marker (moves after insertion) at 749 in *magit: zibann> nil #<marker at 1 in *magit: zibann> nil nil nil nil nil nil #6 nil])] nil] keymap (keymap (65 . magit-stash-pop) (97\
 . magit-stash-apply) (remap keymap (magit-delete-thing . magit-stash-drop) (magit-visit-thing . magit-stash-show))))) "magit:" "calendar util" "reduc" "calendar contain" "toolbar" "gud" "actions" "toolbar" "month" "day" "dates" "web" "view" "py bun" "py" "dates" "viewse\
t" "gud" "produ" "gud" "actions" "day." "js" "/home/eugenekim/Documents/zibann/momsite/apps/reservation/" "reservation calendar" "gud" "bundle" "day" "dates" "gud" "calendar" "day." "calendar " "month" "gud" "py" "month" "gud" "day" "/home/eugenekim/Documents/zibann/moms\
ite/apps/reservation/static/reservation/calendar/actions/" "actions" "base" #("product" 0 7 (fontified t font-lock-face font-lock-string-face)) "/home/eugenekim/Documents/zibann/momsite/apps/saleor/product/rest/viewsets/product/bundle_product/bundle_product.py" "regul" "\
gud" #("product" 0 7 (fontified t font-lock-face font-lock-string-face)) ".js view" "produc" "product py" "/home/eugenekim/Documents/zibann/momsite/apps/reservation/static/reservation/calendar/reducers/" "reducer" "day" "gud" "actions" "mon" "produc py" "js" "month" "dat\
es" "month" "actions" "month" "day" "/home/eugenekim/Documents/zibann/momsite/apps/reservation/static/reservation/calendar/reducers/ind" "/home/eugenekim/Documents/zibann/momsite/apps/reservation/static/reservation/calendar/reducers/dates.react.js" "/home/eugenekim/Docum\
ents/zibann/momsite/apps/reservation/static/reservation/calendar/reducers/" "days" "calendar" "day." "actions"))
```

Comment: Don't run multiple Emacs instances. Run one -- preferably via `emacs --daemon` and then connect with multiple `emacsclient -c` (or `-nw` on terminal) instances.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel oh, I didn't see any use for daemon and now I do. Thanks!

Comment: It is _literally_ the best thing since sliced bread.  Try it, you never go back.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have a question though, when I run two emacs, say I work on two different projects, emacs can manage different command / file opening histories. Wouldn't there be only one such history if I use daemon and everything connects to it?

Comment: Maybe.  That is a feature I have not used in 20+ years of emacs use. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe ask on the Emacs stackexchange site?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: aye, what's the primary reason you like it so much? I see it's fast to load for a start.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel FYI, http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/495/multiple-emacs-instances-each-with-their-own-server shows a solution for what I asked.